# Volley - How to Fetch Newly Updated JSON Item without loading from cache

Tags: android, json

Here is my MainActivity code. It fetches data from a JSON array and shows some random item on click.

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    private TextView qid, quoteTV, authorTV, startReading;
   // private RequestQueue mQueue;
    private ProgressDialog progress;
    public RequestQueue mQueue;
    JSONArray jsonArray;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        startReading = findViewById(R.id.startReading);
        qid = findViewById(R.id.qid);
        quoteTV = findViewById(R.id.quoteTV);
        quoteTV.setVerticalScrollBarEnabled(true);
        quoteTV.setMovementMethod(ScrollingMovementMethod.getInstance());
        quoteTV.setScrollBarStyle(View.SCROLLBARS_INSIDE_INSET);
        authorTV = findViewById(R.id.authorTV);
        final Button buttonParse = findViewById(R.id.button_parse);

        mQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this);

        CardView editProfileLayout = (CardView) findViewById(R.id.authorTVBG);
        editProfileLayout.setVisibility(View.GONE);

        buttonParse.setText("Start Reading");

        buttonParse.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                buttonParse.setText("Next Quote");
                CardView editProfileLayout = (CardView) findViewById(R.id.authorTVBG);
                editProfileLayout.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                quoteTV.setText("");
                authorTV.setText("");


                progress = new ProgressDialog(MainActivity.this);
                progress.setMessage("Loading.. Please Wait");
                progress.setCancelable(false);
                progress.show();

                jsonParse();
                startReading.setText("");
            }
        });
    }


    private void jsonParse() {



        String url = "https://api.myjson.com/bins/1ajohg";

        JsonObjectRequest request = new JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.GET, url, null,
                new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {




                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
                        try {
                            progress.hide();
                            jsonArray = response.getJSONArray("quotes");
                            displayRandomQuote();

                        } catch (JSONException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                    }
                    public void displayRandomQuote(){
                        // Get the total number of quotes
                        int totalQuotes = jsonArray.length();

                        // Pick a random between 0 and the total
                        Random r = new Random();
                        int random = r.nextInt(totalQuotes);

                        try {
                            JSONObject quoteData = jsonArray.getJSONObject(random);
                            int id = quoteData.getInt("id");
                            String quote = quoteData.getString("quote");
                            String author = quoteData.getString("author");

                            quoteTV.setText("“ " + String.valueOf(quote) + " ”");
                            authorTV.setText("Author " + ": " + String.valueOf(author));
                        } catch (JSONException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                    }
                }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
            @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                error.printStackTrace();

            }
        });

        final RequestQueue requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this);
        mQueue.add(request);

        requestQueue.addRequestFinishedListener(new RequestQueue.RequestFinishedListener<Object>() {
            @Override
            public void onRequestFinished(Request<Object> request) {
                mQueue.getCache().clear();
            }
        });

    }}
```

My problem occurs when the JSON gets fetched for the first time. It saves in a local cache. Even if the JSON is updated in the API end point, that won't get reflected in the app, because it loads the data from the cache.

How can I implement the function to fetch the newly updated JSON?
Alternatively, how can I clear the volley cache completely to refetch again?